# Group Algebra of a Discrete Group and Different Notions of a Group Algebra?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, group-rings

I am reading these two wiki articles: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_algebra and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin_duality

From my understanding, the group algebra of a topological group G is the collection of all continuous functions $f : G \to \Bbb{C}$ with compact support, denoted by $C_c(G)$. When $G$ is discrete, compact support implies finite support, so we can identify $f : G \to \Bbb{C}$ with the sum $\sum_{g \in G} f(g) g$, which shows that the group ring and group algebra are isomorphic for discrete groups. Does this sound right?

However, I am confused by a passage in the second link given above:

> This algebra [$L^1(G)$] is referred to as the *Group Algebra* of $G$

What is in fact the group algebra?

Comment: A group algebra is what you said, see wikipedia. For discrete groups, it is the [group ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring), also referred to as group algebra.

Comment: @DietrichBurde So, most people/resources don't refer to $L^1(G)$ as the Group Algebra of $G$?

Comment: It may depend on the context, but usually  "group algebra" is - well, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupAlgebra.html).